# Invoking Custom Media Player in Google Chrome cast from Android application

Tags: android, chromecast

We are trying to invoke a sample Custom Media player HTML 5 app on Chrome cast which has support for Adaptive bit rate streaming protocols like MPEG-DASH, HLS etc from an Android (application) device

The receiver app is in java script running on our server & will be launched on chrome cast device

Its needs the Chrome cast Media Player Java Script Library & we've used it in the Receiver Application.  Currently our sender app is an Android App & can ONLY invoke the "Remote Media player" which can only play MP4 files.

But we want to invoke player which can play adaptive bit rate streaming protocols.
There is an example of invoking custom Media player but this can be launched only from Chrome Browser on desktop Sender App with the support of Chrome cast extension
Sample is below:

Currently Chrome on Android has no support for extensions as per the below update.

Does Chrome for Android support apps and extensions?
**Chrome apps and extensions are currently not supported on Chrome for Android. We have no plans to announce at this time.**

We tried to play MPEG-DASH on default RemoteMediaPlayer i.e using load APIs
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/RemoteMediaPlayer.html

But we could not play links this in default RemoteMediaPlayer even after specifying Mimetype properly.
E.g.:
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/dash/BigBuckBunny/bunny_10s/BigBuckBunny_10s_isoffmain_url_relative_DIS_23009_1_v_2_1c2_2011_08_30.mpd

So we just tried to use the custom Media Player as given in the example "CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM"
But we could NOT invoke trigger the below function without a session from Sender App. 
We could not find Cast SDK  APIs which could invoke below function of custom Media player.

```
mediaManager.onLoad = function(event) {
  mediaHost = new cast.player.api.Host({
    'mediaElement': mediaElement,
    'url': url
  });
}
```

We could only do this from session APIs chrome.cast.Session in Java script & for this we need Chrome cast extension running on Browser.

```
session.loadMedia(request,
    onMediaDiscovered.bind(this, 'loadMedia'),
    onMediaError);
```

As Chrome on Android doesn't support extensions we were checking how we could accomplish loading the custom media receiver.

So please suggest any alternative approach for launching custom media player from an Android device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native Android or iOS SDKs to launch your app on a chromecast; all the apis required for doing that are there and all the apis you would need to send an adaptive or a non-adaptive media to a chromecast from these two platforms are there as well; playing an adaptive vs no-adaptive media is more of an issue for the receiver app not senders, so chrome, Android and iOS all can do the same in that regards.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Ali Naddaf, I have given more details for the problem of launching custom media receiver from Android Application. Could you please let me know an alternative approach.

Comment: Playing MPEG-DASH is more of an effort on the receiver not sender; senders in most cases don't do anything special. You need to try our default or styled receiver and then if that is not adequate (if you have a special authentication or licensing needs), you would then need to write your own custom receiver. it seems to me that you are somewhat confusing receivers and senders in your discussion, I suggest you read up on our design and review our documentations to make yourself more familiar with the platform and what you can do with it.